# Distance from every instance in a collection

Tags: geometry-nodes, mathematics

I'm trying to make a graphical demonstration of how [MeanShift](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mean_shift) works. I have 6 points in a collection, and a geometry node setup to apply a kernel based on the distance of these points from a plane position, then sum all these kernel results. Currently I just do this manually for each point. (see below) Is there some way I could use the Collection Info instances as the source of these positions instead of manually referencing every Object Info?

[image: Nodes]

Here's what the result looks like btw

[image]
[image]

Comment: Collection info node, separate instances, attribute statistic node, position, min. I think. Except a statistic is for a single value, maybe you could convert instances to points and then do geometry proximity to points.

Comment: I'd initially used the Geometry Proximity node, except that's not correct because it will only give the distance from the nearest point. I need to sum the weighted distance from every point.

Comment: you could use *attribute statistics* node and use the sum, or use the *accumulate field* node and use the total.

Answer (score 2):

I don't know what you're doing in your custom groups, which may be crucial for the problem, but if you wanted to sum all locations, you would do it like so:

[image]

[image]

Comment: This looks like a good step, as I do need to sum them. But first I need to find the distance from the point and run it through a Kernel. This is certainly cool and useful though!